# "this.afAuth.authState.map is not a function"

Tags: angular

I want to get but give me error map `this.afAuth.authState.map` is not a function:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root' 
})
export class AuthClientService {
    constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth) { }

    getAuth(){
        return this.afAuth.authState.map(auth=>auth);
    } 
}
```

Comment: While the answer below does provide an example of using pipeable operator `map`, what is the purpose of mapping `auth` to `auth`? You aren't actually doing anything to it and is an unnecessary operation.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky so What is the solution because I am a novice

Comment: My question is why are you trying to do `map` specifically? Are you trying to transform the object coming from `authState`? If you are not trying to do any kind of transformation/manipulation on `authState` you do not need `map`. You could just `return this.afAuth.authState`. Please provide more details on how `getAuth` is being used and what issues you are encountering specifically.

Comment: I assume he wants to do return authState.pipe(map( auth=> { return auth.toJson(); }))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use rxjs pipe to map Observable.

```
this.afAuth.authState.pipe(map(auth=>auth));
```